# Installing NOOBS on SD Card

Tags: mount, ssd, raspberrypi

I need to download NOOBS into a micro sd card so I can boot my raspberry pi, but the MicroSD Card Reader is not 'showing' on my laptop.

I mean, it shows up on    lsusb:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:06b1 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But I can't find the folder to copy the NOOBS files to:

```
~$ ls -la /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov 17 15:06 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Nov 17 15:06 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Nov 17 15:06 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Nov 17 15:06 /dev/sda5
```

Comment: RTS5129 does not work correctly with newer kernels for some reason I ignore. There a supposedly temporary fix at https://github.com/asymingt/rts5139

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have problems finding a special folder when running Ubuntu?